# Drawing in C++ using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a problem with drawing in C++ using Visual Studio 2005. After event handling on MouseMove the results of using DrawLine function appear in PictureBox but if some window overlap the part of PictureBox all pixels in this place dissapear after moving the window. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: C++ itself doesn't have the capability to draw. Is this .NET, CLR, etc?

Answer (score 4):

In your `MouseMove` handler, you just want to store the points where you *will* draw the lines (but don't draw anything at that time). At the end of that handler, call `InvalidateRect` to tell Windows that your window needs re-painting. Windows will (eventually) respond to that with a `WM_PAINT` message. When you receive the WM_PAINT message, retrieve the points and do the actual drawing.

If you're doing anything other than bare Win32 programming, chances are that whatever framework you're using will handle a few bits and pieces of that for you, but the general structure normally remains roughly the same.